# no file save dialog for snap applications

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04, fuse, keepassxc

using a fresh ubuntu 22.04 install i can no longer save or download any files in firefox. it did work when i first installed firefox, now it no longer does.

```
File -> Save page as
```

does not even open a window where i could select a destination directory.

using the "save as" button in the pdf viewer also does nothing at all.

i just started firefox in safe mode

```
$ firefox --safe-mode
```

and saw the error message

> (firefox:9161): Gtk-WARNING **: 09:19:12.367: Can't open portal file
> chooser: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The
> name org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop was not provided by any .service
> files

this (probably) goes for all snap applications. for me it was

- `firefox`
- `keepassxc`

---

i might have uninstalled `fuse3` and `xdg-desktop-portal` when i installed `fuse`. [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404988/fuse-and-fuse3-can-i-install-both).

Comment: i want to BEAT whoever decided it was a nice idea to force firefox on us as a snap

Answer (score 19, accepted):

oh, after some more investigation i found out i had to install

```
$ sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

and everything worked again.

as mentioned in the comments: you may have to reboot after installing the packages.

Comment: Do you also notice that, a second time you summon the Save As dialog, that it has no keyboard focus?

Comment: Yes you can, because now you have a Save dialog. My question is of you hit Ctrl+S, does the dialog that appears also have keyboard focus? Perhaps you always use a mouse so will never notice.

Comment: ok, i tired. yes, the dialog has keyboard focus (although the first time i tired firefox crashed).

Comment: Not for me, even not with a default fresh install in Gnome Boxes. Second time in a session I open the dialog, I cannot navigate in the dialog with the keyboard nor use escape to close it.

Comment: what helped for me was to start firefox from a terminal so i got some error messages.

Comment: this didn't work for me, it says already the latest version is installed

Comment: After installing the packages I had to reboot for it to work

Comment: Same thing here, I had to reboot after installing the packages for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I already had the two packages installed, so I had to

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force depends xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
```

Afterwards, it works. Let's see if it still works after reboot.

Also see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1851104