# fuse and fuse3 - can i install both?

Tags: 22.04, fuse

i am using a cloud service that provides a sync app which depends on `fuse`. when i try to install `fuse` i get

```
$ sudo apt install fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fuse3 xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuse
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1’577 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

which will remove `fuse3` and `xdg-desktop-portal` (which has [this effect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404941/can-not-download-save-any-files-from-firefox-snap)).

is there a way to have both,  `fuse` and `fuse3` installed? or is there a different workaround?

Comment: I do not think at least not with apt.. `apt show fuse3`  shows `Breaks: fuse Replaces: fuse`

Comment: The app of the cloud service needs to be updated to support fuse3.

Comment: @vanadium that is what i feared. i contacted their support... thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i got a reply back from my cloud provider. their suggestion is to just install `libfuse2` (without the command line tool `fuse`):

```
$ sudo apt install libfuse2
```

and everything seems to work just fine.