# Firefox installed from snap cannot save files to disk

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04

after updating Kubuntu from 20 to 22, Firefox has been forcefully installed from snap. After that, I cannot download and save any file at any place, not only in home directory. I've given all explicit permissions to Firefox in the Kubuntu's software manager (Discover) with no effect. Also, I have a similar problems in other apps installed from snap. What else can I try to do to give all permissions to those apps?

UPD1. The previous Kubuntu version was 20.04.4. I updated to 22.04.

UPD2. Output for `snap connections firefox`

```
Interface                 Plug                            Slot                             Notes
audio-playback            firefox:audio-playback          :audio-playback                  -
audio-record              firefox:audio-record            :audio-record                    -
avahi-observe             firefox:avahi-observe           :avahi-observe                   -
browser-support           firefox:browser-sandbox         :browser-support                 -
camera                    firefox:camera                  :camera                          -
content[gnome-3-38-2004]  firefox:gnome-3-38-2004         gnome-3-38-2004:gnome-3-38-2004  -
content[gtk-3-themes]     firefox:gtk-3-themes            gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes   -
content[icon-themes]      firefox:icon-themes             gtk-common-themes:icon-themes    -
content[sound-themes]     firefox:sound-themes            gtk-common-themes:sound-themes   -
cups-control              firefox:cups-control            :cups-control                    -
dbus                      -                               firefox:dbus-daemon              -
desktop                   firefox:desktop                 :desktop                         -
desktop-legacy            firefox:desktop-legacy          :desktop-legacy                  -
gsettings                 firefox:gsettings               :gsettings                       -
hardware-observe          firefox:hardware-observe        :hardware-observe                -
home                      firefox:home                    :home                            manual
joystick                  firefox:joystick                :joystick                        -
mpris                     -                               firefox:mpris                    -
network                   firefox:network                 :network                         -
network-observe           firefox:network-observe         :network-observe                 manual
opengl                    firefox:opengl                  :opengl                          -
personal-files            firefox:dot-mozilla-firefox     :personal-files                  -
removable-media           firefox:removable-media         :removable-media                 -
screen-inhibit-control    firefox:screen-inhibit-control  :screen-inhibit-control          -
system-files              firefox:etc-firefox-policies    :system-files                    -
system-packages-doc       firefox:system-packages-doc     :system-packages-doc             -
u2f-devices               firefox:u2f-devices             :u2f-devices                     -
unity7                    firefox:unity7                  :unity7                          -
upower-observe            firefox:upower-observe          :upower-observe                  -
wayland                   firefox:wayland                 :wayland                         -
x11                       firefox:x11                     :x11                             -
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1285102/289138 - then google for a ppa / deb on firefox, it is out there

Comment: If you upgraded a Ubuntu Core 20 system to 22; no user application will be changed which is one of the benefits of the *year* based products (20 & 22).  On the 20.04 to 22.04 or *year.month* products all non-snap applications get changed.  20 & 20.04 are different Ubuntu products. Snap packages run *confined* which has security benefits, but those security benefits incur limitations; some directories can be enabled (`snap connect`) where as others cannot. You've not specified.  Please be precise with details (20 != 20.04 & 22 != 22.04)

Comment: If you cannot save files in your home directory, that's a bug -- please report it to the Mozilla bug tracker with enough detail for a developer to reproduce the issue. If you are regularly saving files outside your home directory, that is usage that the Mozilla developers did not foresee -- we will need more details to know if using snaps that way can be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added some info to the post.

Comment: I agree with @user535733 This is likely buggy behavior, possible at the level of xdg-portal. Select a folder in your home directory, you cannot save. Make a new one: you can save there, select the previous folder on the path bar - now you can save. If that is not buggy, then the logic of the design is not clear to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi While it is fine to refer to that answer for providing the option to move to deb, it is intellectually unfair marking this as a duplicate and avoid any answer to the current question about the snap version that comes by default with the distribution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing files outside of /home in snap apps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228899/accessing-files-outside-of-home-in-snap-apps)

Comment: @karel thanks, as I added previously in the post, all necessary connections are established (at least it looks so). I've reported a bug on bugzilla

Comment: @ArtemPlyusnin I'm sorry for being dumb. I was just being careful that you enabled connections to removable devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no file save dialog for snap applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404941/no-file-save-dialog-for-snap-applications)