# Snap applications can't open file dialog in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: firefox, 22.04, filemanager, inkscape, restricted-access

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Recently, when I try to open files from any application such as inkscape or firefox, it appears the application is unable to access the file dialog.

For example, when I try to download files using firefox and select save in a different location, the file dialog doesn't show up.

In inkscape, when I try to open existing files, the file dialog doesn't show up.

Please comment if you have faced a similar problem or have some clues about how to fix it.

Comment: To make it more clear, replace the term "file browser" by "file dialog". The "File browser" would be the file manager, Files. What you (don't but expect to) see, is not the file browser, but a dedicated GTK file dialog (which looks a lot like Files). Firefox will be a snap application. How is Inkscape installed? Also as a snap?

Comment: Yes inkscape is also installed using snap

Comment: Thanks @vanadium, with your comment I found the solution here.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404941/no-file-save-dialog-for-snap-applications

Comment: Great! In this case, you may want to delete this question, or mark it as a duplicate to that other question.